# Which Nomai skeletons can be positively identified?

Tags: outer-wilds

Throughout most of the Nomai ruins in the solar system, numerous Nomai skeletons are found lying around. Based on the Nomai's message logs and other evidence, it should be possible to identify many of these. Off the top of my head, I can identify the following:

> Poke, Pye, and Clary on the Interloper (Clary in the shuttle, Poke & Pye inside the comet)

> Idaea on the Sun Station

> Avens & Mallow in the Orbital Probe Cannon

I wonder, how many of the other Nomai skeletons found throughout the solar system can be identified in a similar manner? Do they all correspond to named characters, or do some belong to Nomai whose writing we never get to read?

Comment: Solanum is a pretty obvious one; comments can't have spoiler tags or I'd go into more detail.